# How can I display different "screens"/views from an activity?

Tags: android

I am new to developing on android, finding myself somewhat confused regarding fragments and activities, and when to use the former specifically.

I want to achieve the following:

Have an activity with buttons for displaying different graphs. The selected graph should appear on screen in a panel overlaying the screen, or in fullscreen, and it should have functionality/buttons e.g. for selecting a graph timeframe.

Would creating each graph-page as fragments, routing events to the main activity be a good idea here, or should I just make a new activity for each? Or are there better options?

Cheers

Comment: you should probably learn how to use fragments because fragments are used to achieve tasks something like exactly you mentioned. Using different activities would be a mess and complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend to use separate activities for this task.

The fragments are a great option for your case. You can save the state of each fragment and thus avoid recreating the graph views every time (which saves lots of CPU time if amount of data is big).

Read info about [FragmentTransaciton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html) and of course learn about working with Fragments in general. Maybe you should also try using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) if you want to avoid switching fragments by yourself.

In case of using ViewPager you should use FragmentPagerAdapter (this one saves fragments for you) and you will just switch between them from your MainActivity. In each of the fragments you will implement your own graph with its own (or shared) layout file.

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of tabs. The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.

Comment: Thanks! I have started up studying fragments. Seems like a fit!